# iOS Keyboard and Custom Buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, iphone-keypad

How can I  embed custom keyboard buttons inside the iOS Default keyboard, like the ["UP" app by Jawbone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/up-by-jawbone/id461125277?mt=8) has done in the picture below.

[image]

I am looking to **embed an "@" button identically to how the app has done it** (I don't need the # button). I have found ways to add buttons above the keyboard or change the keyboard style (the email style includes the @ button but adds unneccessary ones and makes the space button to small) but no way to seamlessly integrate it like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a custom button, that is the `keyboardType` `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter`.